# CSS Mega Menu - one tab open on page load - jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, megamenu

I am using [this](http://themes.pixelworkshop.fr/?theme=CSS3MegaMenu) mega menu

What I would like is for one tab (the second tab) to be open when the page loads without someone having to hover over it first - I would still need it to change to the other tab contents if a different one is hovered though. I tried adding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.menu li.fullwidth:first div.dropdown_fullwidth').css('left','0px');
});
```

which kept the content open but didnt have the tabs hover state nor did it change when i hover on another - can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I would just question why you need to pop open a dropdown like that? But probably something like would do the trick:

```
$("li:first div").show()
```

Edit:

Ok I see the issue sorry:

you'll need to take the hover css and apply it to the button with a .select class with the same styles then add:

```
$("li:first a").addClass("selected");
```

You'll then have to remove it on rollover of any of the other buttons:

```
$("li a").hover(function(){
   $("li:first a").removeClass("selected");
})
```

I'll be honest that's really hacky and horrible, but I not sure there is other way to apply it without a lot of re-writing of the CSS.  I'd personally suggest considering why you want to do this a look for a better solution by considering your navigation structure.

Comment: that does absolutely nothing.